# an error and warning appearing in my php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am receiving 2 errors in my code below:

> Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: (21S01/1136): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in ... on line 115

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ... on line 119

I am using mysqli and php code. What do I need to do in order to fix these errors?

CODE:

```
$insertsql = "
INSERT INTO Teacher
(TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherEmail, TeacherAlias, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Code)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}                                           

$insert->bind_param("sssssss", $getfirstname, $getsurname,
         $getemail, $getid, $getuser,
         $teacherpassword, $code);

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();
```

Comment: You have 7 parameters, and 8 `?` in the VALUES; delete one of the `?`, and see if that makes both messages go away....

Comment: @andrewsi I thought I removed the ? but I can clearly see I havn't. Sorry and thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @jprofitt - that's how mysqli deals with bound parameters - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @andrewsi You are absolutely correct. Been working in PDO-land for too long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many parameters in your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Teacher 
    (TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherEmail, TeacherAlias, TeacherUsername,   
    TeacherPassword, Code)
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

There are 7 columns and 8 parameters.